# the last cell on collectionview can't be seen in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem.
I have a collectionView on view and cells on the collectionView.
The cell size is itemSize, the collectionView size is contentSize adjusted in didLayoutSubViems but the last cell can’t be seen now.
Any help?Thank you.

Comment: there must be some conflict with cell height size and collectionview size height or some contraints problem

Comment: Can you provide code of itemsize of cell so that I can check what is the reason?

Comment: `
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth / 2 - 15, screenWidth / 2 - 15)
 
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
       super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
       myCollectionView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width - 20, 750)
     }` @PayalManiyar

Comment: `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() { super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() myCollectionView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width - 20, 750) }`why you have changed size here?

Comment: @PayalManiyar That's because I want to change the size after autolayout process.

Answer (score 0):

```
     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                            layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                                   sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
   {
    return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width - 20, 750)
   }
```

Try above line of code. Hope it will help you....

Comment: Thanks.                                                                                                      `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                       layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                              sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
   {
//        myCollectionView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width - 20, 750)
       
       return CGSize(width: screenWidth / 2 - 15, height: screenWidth / 2)
   }` I got "missing return" error so i changed but it just changed the cell size.